# What does "given to" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

A [dictionary definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sharp--tongued?q=sharp-tongued) of "sharp-tongued" reads:

> (of a person) given to using cutting, harsh, or critical language."

What does "given to" mean?

I don't understand why "given to" is used here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A person is "[given to](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/given+to)" something if they have a tendency or likelihood of doing that thing.

Comment: Got it. Ok. then, if I say someone is likely to nurish feelings of hatred, can I say he is given to a hatred?

Comment: @dennylv - I might say he is "given to feelings of hate," or maybe even "given to hatred," but **not** "given to **a** hatred. (You wouldn't use an article when saying someone is _given to_ a particular emotion.) I'd probably just say, "He tends to hate things," though.